# Filter list of tuples for tuples that contain certain items python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like so:

```
a = [('1', '2', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
     ('1', '3', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
     ('1', '3', '4', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
     ('1', '4', '4', '4', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
     ('1', '5', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w')]
```

I want to be able to filter out the tuples that contain certain items. For example, I want to find all the tuples that contain `'5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'` specifically and place them in a list.

```
filter_for = ['5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w']
```

Expected result would be:

```
result =  [('1', '2', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
           ('1', '3', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w')]
```

`filter_for` will have a varying length of 1 to 7 so I using `and` is not going to be ideal.

I've tried using

```
[i for i in a if all(j in filtered_for for j in a)]
```

but that doesn't work.

EDIT: If `('1', '5', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w')` was also in the list I wouldn't want that tuple to be found. I guess I didn't specify this as all working solutions below would return this tuple as well.

Comment: 1. What does *"doesn't seem to work"* mean, precisely? 2. If you want to match the correct *positions* of those elements, why not `zip` it?

Comment: Are all elements of `a` and all elements of `filter_for` always 1-character strings?

Comment: Your edit makes this question too subjective. Are you stating that if the head or tail of the sequence has `array[head - 1] == array[head]` or `array[tail] == array[tail + 1]` the filter should fail?

Comment: @Robᵩ yes, all elements of a and all elements of filter_for are always 1 character strings

Comment: Hmm, going to update my answer shortly.

Comment: I'm really curious what this problem is actually trying to solve. Seems like a vary convoluted data structure.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov the tuples in list `a` are dice rolls with 8 six-sided dice. One side of the dice is a 'w' instead of a 6. I'm trying to filter for certain score totals, where a specific set of sides exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this should return the expected results. Here we convert the lists to strings, and use [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) to check for membership.

```
>>> a = [('1', '2', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
 ('1', '3', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
 ('1', '3', '4', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
 ('1', '4', '4', '4', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w')]
>>> filter_for = ''.join(['5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'])
>>> print [tup for tup in a if filter_for in ''.join(tup)]
[('1','2','5','5','w','w','w','w'), ('1','3','5','5','w','w','w','w')]
```

---

The below code has been updated to match **exact** sub-lists in the list of tuples. Instead of *pattern matching* like in the example above, we take a far different approach here.

We start off by finding the `head` and `tail` of the filter list. We then find the the indices of where the `head` and `tail` occur in `tup` (*we must reverse* `tup` *to find the* `tail_index`*, as* `index` *returns only the **first** element matched*). Using our indices pair, we can then slice that sublist spanning the distance between `head` and `tail`. If this sublist **matches** the filter, then we know that *only* that range exists in the search tuple.

```
def match_list(filter_list, l):
    results = []
    filter_for = tuple(filter_list)
    head = filter_for[0]
    tail = filter_for[-1]

    for tup in l:
        reverse_tup = tup[::-1]
        if head and tail in tup:
            try:
                head_index = tup.index(head)
                index_key = reverse_tup.index(tail)
                tail_index = -index_key if index_key else None
                if tup[head_index:tail_index] == filter_for:
                    results.append(tup)  # Prints out condition-satisfied tuples.
            except ValueError:
                continue
    return results
```

**Sample output**

```
 >>> a = [('1', '2', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
 ('1', '3', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
 ('1', '3', '4', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
 ('1', '4', '4', '4', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
 ('1', '5', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w')]  # <- Does not match!
 >>> filter_for = ['5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w']
 >>> print match_list(filter_for, a)
 [('1','2','5','5','w','w','w','w'), ('1','3','5','5','w','w','w','w')]
```

Comment: @hopla, I've made changes to handle your latest edit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure If I get the point what you're trying. But I would do it as following:

```
>>>[i for i in a if "".join(filter_for) in "".join(i)]
[('1', '2', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'), ('1', '3', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w')]
```

Comment: This works correctly if all of the elements are 1-character strings. It might not work in other cases.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean. Can you explain it to me? It would work on that a = [('11', '22', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w')] so what do you mean? Thanks

Comment: 1) The point is moot. OP has clarified that all input are 1-character strings. 2) Consider `a = [['12', '34']]; filter_for = ['2', '3']`. Your solution would find a match, even though it isn't present. 3) Consider `a = [['1', 4.75]]; filter_for = ['1']`. Your solution will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this

```
[i for i in a if all([j in i for j in filter_for])]
```

instead of your line?

```
[i for i in a if all(j in filter_for for j in a)]
```

Comment: both should work `all(j in filter_for for j in a)` iterates over the generator `(j in filter_for for j in a)`. You don't need to add parens around the generator expression when it is the only argument of a function.

Answer (score -1):

This code seems to work, it tests every list by dividing them in several lists of the same length as `filter_for`

**Edit**: I tried to add some excluded patterns after your edit

```
a = [('1', '2', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
     ('1', '3', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
     ('1', '3', '4', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
     ('1', '4', '4', '4', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w'),
     ('1', '5', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w')]

filter_for = ['5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w']
excluded = [('1', '5', '5', '5', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w')]

# add a padding key to excluded patterns
for x in range(len(excluded)):
    value = excluded[x]
    excl = {'value': value}

    for i in range(len(value) - len(filter_for) + 1):
        if list(value[i:i+len(filter_for)]) == list(filter_for):
            excl['padding'] = (i, len(value) - i - len(filter_for))

    excluded[x] = excl


def isexcluded(lst, i):
    # check if the lst is excluded by one of the `excluded` lists
    for excl in excluded:
        start_padding, end_padding = excl['padding']

        # get start and end indexes
        start = max(i-start_padding, 0)
        end = min(i + len(excl['value']) + end_padding, len(lst))

        if list(lst[start:end]) == list(excl['value']):
            return True

    return False


def get_lists(lists, length, excluded):
    for lst in lists:
        # get all the 'sublist', parts of the list that are of the same
        # length as filter_for
        for i in range(len(lst)-length+1):
            tests = [list(lst[i:i+length]) == list(filter_for),
                     not isexcluded(lst, i)]

            if all(tests):
                yield lst

result = list(get_lists(a, len(filter_for), excluded))

print(result)  # python 2: print result
```